# Using HTML5 and CSS display 2 images level with each other, and each with a list below

Tags: css, html, scrollbar, margin

I'm new to CSS. I want to code a page in HTML5 that has 2 rather large images of equal size and level with each other and with space between them. I also want a left-margin between the left image and the left edge of the page.

Directly below each image there will be an unnumbered list of 6 or so items. Would someone be so kind as to draft the code for this? I know one way to use CSS for spacing the images:

img
{
margin-right: 38px;
margin-left: 50px;
}

But what to do about the lists?

Thanks

Comment: You need to illustrate at least some attempt (code, research, etc.) at solving this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't provided any sample code, I'm just going to shoot and guess if this is close to what you need. Check out this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UeU55/1/).

I assume you have 2 identical sections. Basically they are the same, displayed inline but with different contents. I have added the margins you wished, but if you need something more, I'm going to need you to tell me.

In short, the idea is having a HTML element (one, two or however you want) of the same class with identical content:

```
<div class="smth">
  <img src="smth.jpg" />

  <ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get the 2 images and their lists to appear beside each other on the page ("at the same level")?

Comment: Try to illustrate this with an simple sketch or something so I can get the idea, it's not clear that way. Then, when I get it, I'll show you how you should do it.

Comment: Actually, the right image would be different from the left one, but of the same dimensions.

Comment: Basically, what I have provided you with is exactly the same as the one on your image. Here's a slightly updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/UeU55/2/

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much! I don't understand all of it, but I think now that I can figure it out with the help of http://www.w3schools.com/ , the best site I've found so far.

Comment: I competed the page using the sample code. But a friend pointed out that when the browser window isn't wide enough to show http://www.rcblue.com/images/JSFIDDLE_full_window.jpg , what it shows is http://www.rcblue.com/images/JSFIDDLE_narrowed_window.jpg . How can I modify the code so that a narrow browser window, instead showing the overlapping mess and the vertical alignment of the images, a horizontal bar is made available to the viewer to scroll to the right?

Comment: I should have added that I now know that I could use a table to accomplish this. However, I've read that tables should be used solely for data, of the sort that go into spreadsheets. I'd like to see how it can be done with HTML5 and CSS, with no use of a table.

Comment: That happens, because we have fixed widths for our `.section` div. Take a look at CSS3 Media Queries. The idea is to target a specific width and tell the browser how this should look in a particular case. This is usually used for targeting mobile devices and tablets.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give me a specific recommendation for CSS3 Media Queries? There seem to be several sites that have them.

Comment: Look through all of them. Anything for them will be useful to you, since you are a beginner in that area.